# Update using having and MIN function non key-preserved table error

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-update

I have below data in two different tables. I am able to retrieve required records using select query, however I am unable to update `ROW_IND` of these records. The update statement I used gives me error. Any pointers will be much appreciated.

> **Table CLP :**

```
ID              KEY     EFF_DT              ROW_IND
28420000000006  4599    1/1/2000                1
28420000000006  21164   10/16/2019              1
28420000000011  58429   1/1/2000                1
28420000000011  68434   10/16/2019              1
```

> **Table CPI :**

```
KEY2    ID2 
21164   28420000000006
68434   28420000000011
```

> **The Query :**

```
SELECT  p.id ,  p.key, i.key AS KEY2, i.id AS ID2, p.EFF_DT, p.row_ind
  FROM CLP P, CLI I
 WHERE p.id = i.id
   AND P.KEY <> I.KEY
   AND p.row_ind = 1
   AND P.id IN
              (
                SELECT id 
                  FROM CLP
                 WHERE row_ind = 1
                 GROUP BY id
                 HAVING count(*) > 1
               );


ID              KEY      KEY2   ID2             EFF_DT          ROW_IND
28420000000006  4599    21164   28420000000006  1/1/2000                1
28420000000011  58429   68434   28420000000011  1/1/2000                1
```

**The Update Query:**

```
UPDATE 
(
 < The Above SELECT Query >
) A
SET A.row_ind  = 0
```

> **Error:** **ORA-01779**: *cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table*

Answer (score 1):

This syntax for an `UPDATE` statement cannot be used within Oracle while might be used within MySQL. Alternatively, you can try to use a `MERGE` statement :

```
MERGE INTO CLP t
    USING 
        (
          SELECT  p.id ,  p.key, i.key AS KEY2, i.id AS ID2, p.EFF_DT, p.row_ind
            FROM CLP p
            JOIN CPI i 
              ON p.id = i.id
           WHERE p.key <> i.key
             AND p.row_ind = 1
             AND P.id in
              (
              SELECT id 
                FROM CLP
               WHERE row_ind = p.row_ind
               GROUP BY id
              HAVING count(*) > 1
              ) 
         ) tt
      ON (tt.key2 = t.key)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET t.row_ind = 0;
```

where

- you'd better converting the old-style `SELECT` statement to the
  syntax containing explicit `JOIN` keywords instead of comma-seperated
  `JOIN`s
- no need to repeat the condition `row_ind = 1` twice, replacing the
  second one with `row_ind = p.row_ind` is more preferable

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=df60f2aa634d4f3a74cbd38d638dd578)</kbd>